# checking diffs in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce, usability

This may be unrelated to programming but does helps in it.
We use Jenkins with perforce plugin. Jenkins build is triggered by change. We can also see which files got affect in the specific changelist.

But I was curious if there is any option by which we can also see the diff between the files.
Say a changelist says : **hello.cpp 2#2**
So is there any way I can see the diff between 1st and 2nd version of hello.cpp file. As if there is such feature it will allow us to review the code and increase the usability.

Comment: What source control system are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an scm browser server such as fisheye or p4web, and set up the perforce plugin to talk to it. That will provide links to the diffs for each file in the changelog.

Comment: Never know it was like adding just 2 parameters. Answers from developer itself is indeed helpful. Thanks